# "No Kernel!" error Azure ML compute JupyterLab

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

When using the JupyterLab found within the azure ML compute instance, every now and then, I run into an issue where it will say that network connection is lost.

I have confirmed that the computer is still running.
the notebook itself can be edited and saved, so the computer/VM is definitely running
Of course, the internet is fully functional

On the top right corner *next to the now blank circle* it will say "No Kernel!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't repro the issue, can you help gives us more details? One possibility is that the kernel has bugs and hangs (could be due to extensions, widgets installed) or the resources on the machine are exhausted and kernel dies. What VM type are you using? If it's a small VM you may ran out of resources.

Comment: This is not a self hosted system. Its a compute instance running on top of azure. I think it is probably a azure issue and nothing to do with VM (azure manages the VM, not me), resources on the machine are exhausted (may be, but again, I have no control over it as its azure hosted)

Comment: okay, looks like the compute instance was indeed running too many things I switched to a higher powered VM when running complicated runs.

Answer (score 0):

Having troubleshooted the internet I found that you can force a reconnect (if you wait long enough, like a few minutes, it will do on its own) by using Kernel > Restart Kernel.

Based on my own experience, it seems like this is a fairly common issue but I did spend a few minutes figuring it out. Hope this helps others who are using this.

Answer (score 0):

Check your browser console for any language-pack loading errors.

Part of our team had this issue this week, the root cause for us was some language-packs for pt-br not loading correctly, once the affected team members changed the page/browser language to en-us the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I have been dealing with the same issue, after some research around this problem I learnt my firewall was blocking JupyterLab, Jupyter and terminal, allowing the access to it solved the issue.

Comment: How did you check that your firewall was blocking?